# Can I disable one of the tabs in the bottomtabnavigator? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have used react navigation's `createBottomTabNavigator`.

As can be seen in the code below, if it is in `!this.props.isLoading` status, it is directed to Cart or Payment tabs. I had a problem here, if there are very fast transitions between tabs, there may be incorrect returns from API requests.

That's why I want to disable the tabs for a short time, but I could not succeed. Is there anyone who can help with this?

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


</Tab.Navigator>
initialRouteName="Home"
screenOptions={({route}) => ({
      tabBarVisible: this.props.isTabBarVisible,
      unmountOnBlur: true,
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
        let iconName;
        switch (route.name) {
          case 'Home':
            return (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
                  this.props.navigation.canGoBack();
                }}>
                <View style={styles.Tabs__iconContainer}>
                  <Icon
                    type="ionicon"
                    name={'home'}
                    color={color}
                    size={size - 4}
                  />
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            );
          case 'Customer':
            return (
              <View style={styles.Tabs__iconContainer}>
                <Icon
                  type="ionicon"
                  name={'person'}
                  color={color}
                  size={size - 4}
                />
                {this.customerCount ? (
                  <Badge
                    value={this.customerCount}
                    textStyle={styles.Tabs__customerTickTextStyle}
                    status={'success'}
                    containerStyle={styles.Tabs__badgeContainer}
                    badgeStyle={styles.Tabs__customerBadgeStyle}
                  />
                ) : null}
              </View>
            );
          case 'Cart':
            let totalProductCount = this.props.productList.reduce(
              (x, y) => x + y.quantity,
              0,
            );
            return (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => {
                  if (!this.props.isLoading) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart');
                    }, 100);
                  }
                }}>
                <View
                  style={[styles.Tabs__iconContainer, {paddingTop: '11%'}]}>
                  <Icon
                    type="ionicon"
                    name={'basket'}
                    color={color}
                    size={size + 1}
                  />
                  {totalProductCount > 0 ? (
                    <Badge
                      value={totalProductCount}
                      textStyle={
                        totalProductCount < 10
                          ? styles.Tabs__basketAmountLow
                          : totalProductCount < 100
                          ? styles.Tabs__basketAmountMedium
                          : totalProductCount < 1000
                          ? styles.Tabs__basketAmountHigh
                          : styles.Tabs__basketAmountHighest
                      }
                      status={'success'}
                      containerStyle={styles.Tabs__badgeContainer}
                      badgeStyle={styles.Tabs__basketBadgeStyle}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            );
          case 'Payment':
            return (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => {
                  if (!this.props.isLoading) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      this.props.navigation.navigate('Payment');
                    }, 100);
                  }
                }}>
                <View
                  style={[styles.Tabs__iconContainer, {paddingTop: '11%'}]}>
                  <Icon
                    type="ionicon"
                    name={'card-outline'}
                    color={color}
                    size={size + 1}
                  />
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            );
        }
        return (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingTop: 12}}
            type="ionicon"
            name={iconName}
            color={color}
            size={size}
          />
        );
      },
      title: '',
    })}
................
    <Tab.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
        {configuration.paymentProviders.length > 0 && (
          <Tab.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment} />
    )}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: hey, by disabling the tab, you mean disabling the onPress for the tab right?

Comment: Yeah! What I expect is that when the tab is clicked, it doesn't work during that time.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest answer, but I would recommend adding a state to  help with it.

`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);`

Then put a conditional statement in every `Tab` where you want to disable its `onPress`, in the following example, I added `!loading` to the `if` so it won't trigger another navigation when clicked.

```
case 'Payment':
        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={() => {
              if (!this.props.isLoading && !loading) {
                setLoading(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                  setLoading(false);
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Payment');
                }, 100);
              }
            }}>
            <View
              style={[styles.Tabs__iconContainer, {paddingTop: '11%'}]}>
              <Icon
                type="ionicon"
                name={'card-outline'}
                color={color}
                size={size + 1}
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
```